# Convert to nginx rules

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

Good day, anyone can help me convert this .htaccess to nginx?

.httacess

```
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ ./$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ ./$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

I tried a lot of things, but I just can't get the right formula to make it work. This is my configuration, right now:

```
location /dev/links {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/([^/]+)/$ /$1 redirect;
  }
  rewrite ^/(.+)\.php$ /$1 redirect;
  rewrite ^/([^/.]+)$ /$1.php last;
}
```

This is not root directory if not subdirectory /dev/links